# how to use subclipse with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I want to download the android-pdf project using subclipse with Eclipse.  I have installed subclipse on Eclipse and restarted Eclipse.   I have tried going to File>Import but although there is a CVS option I cannot see a SVN option.  The project is on Google Project Hosting, I have clicked on 'import Google Hosted Project' from the Eclipse taskbar - that displays the 'Select Google Hosted Project' but no projects are displayed.  I hope someone will be able to help me download this project.

Comment: Hm, there _should_ be an option _Import -> SVN -> Checkout Project from SVN_. Can you open the _SVN Repositories_ view and checkout the project form there?

Comment: Cant see SVN anywhere in Eclipse.   The Installation Details windows shows Subclipse as installed.

Answer (score 2):

This question was posted long time back but I am replying for someone coming to this link. One can check [this link](http://pallandri.blogspot.com/2014/01/using-subclipse-with-eclipse-and.html) also. Here is the complete step by step process of installing and connecting to google code:

Go to Eclipse Help menu and click on "Install New Software"
Install Subclipse: 
Add the following site for subclipse
[http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x/](http://subclipse.tigris.org/update%5f1.10.x/)
Select both "Subclipse" and "SVNKit" from the names which appear after adding the subclipse link
Click Next, accept conditions and let eclipse download and install subclipse
Now restart Eclipse after the installation
Subclipse will be ready to use now
Go to "preferences" under the windows menu
Go to "Team" in the left menu and then select "SVN" sub-menu
In the "General SVN Setting" select Team and "SVN" sub-menu
Select SVNKit (Pure Java)--- in the "SVN interface" drop-down menu
Next step is to connect subclipse with google code

First we have to create a project. Instructions for creating a project can be found on
Creating Project on Google Code

Once a project has been created on the Google Code, Subclipse has to be connected to the project.

Go to Eclipse, Click on "Windows" menu, "Show View" and select "Other"
Select "SVN' and "SVN Repositories" and click OK.
Right Click in the "SVN Repositories" tab and choose "New" - "Repository Location"
"Add SVN Repository" window opens.
For the Location URL, give your URL which should be like  [https://your_url.googlecode.com/svn/trunk](https://your%5furl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk)
In my case the URL is "https://agent-desktop.googlecode.com/svn/trunk" for the project which was created in Creating Project on Google Code post. Click Finish after providing the URL
After Finishing you will be asked for the username and the password
this password can be found on project home page under the SVN tab. Search for the link googlecode.com password
Under the Source -> Checkout, Click the link (googlecode.com password) and save the generated password.
Now the Subclipse is connected to the Google code

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see a "SVN" group in the File > Import dialog then that implies Subclipse is not installed.  If it were installed, there would be nothing preventing that grouping from being displayed.

I would normally recommend opening the SVN Repository perspective and adding the repository.  But I would guess you do not see that either.